# How to tell if wall got waterdamage?

Tags: drywall, mold, water-damage

I had a dishwasher flood, due to plumber putting it in wrong. I had the hard wood floor replaced, the cabinets have mold on bottom of it, and the sides that I can see are bubbled up to about half way up. First how should this be repaired? At first they said something about a skin? But I think all the wet boards should be removed and all the bottom due to the spots I saw that had mold?

Second, we have two walls that I know got wet, the base board is all discolored and will be replaced. But what about the wall how do I know for sure the wall is OK. Do I need a mold inspector? Is there a good chance there is mold?

The person taking care of this said the dry wall was OK, but is same person that said something about putting skin over the cabinets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are getting very questionable advice.

Wet drywall needs to be cut out and replaced. Damp drywall is a prime source of mold.  Cabinets that are bubbled halfway up have major water damage and may not be easily repaired.

You should consider getting an independent inspector to assess the damage and the repairs needed. If their view is significantly different from the position of the plumber (or his insurance company) you can try to get them to pay for the cost of inspection.

Comment: hard to tell if the dry wall was wet as its been about a month, plenty of time for it to try. The advice i been getting is from the people paying for it ofcourse :D

Comment: If the baseboard was wet and moldy, the bottom of the drywall was wet.

Answer (score 0):

You need to hire a remediation company that specializes in water damage.  Some things need to be replaced and before they're put back together a professional dryout needs to be done. It may take time for mold to develop but it will develop so putting out a petri dish at this time may not convince anyone more work needs to be done.